# Google Docs API Key on Frontend of Angular Application - How Should I Ensure Security?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am planning on using [this Google Docs API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) in order to allow my Angular application to access the HTML version of a Google Doc, and display it in the form of a CNN, WSJ, etc looking article.

This will all be done on the frontend (I am not running a backend).

The documentation page says:

> Note: Authorization optional.

But it still requires you to provide an API key, as shown by the [endpoint's tester](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export?apix=true). Am I missing something?

Assuming an API key is required, my concern is: If I use this endpoint on the frontend, the public will be able to see my API key. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions) it says you can restrict your API key to only a particular URL. Will this completely solve my security problem (as the API will only accept requests from my site's URL)? Otherwise what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

API keys are only used for accessing public data so if the data isnt owned by a user you can use an api key to access that api.  This way google can track who is using their api.

> If I use this endpoint on the frontend, the public will be able to see my API key.

This is a known consern with client side languages using api keys.  When you create your api key you should create it with restricted access if you can if this is hosted you can create Website restrictions which will mean that your api key can only be used from your website and wont be usable out side.

So i sugest you just check out restricting your api key which should prevent it from being used by others.

> How do I restrict my API key to specific websites?
>   Use an HTTP referrer to restrict the URLs that can use an API key.
>
> Here are some examples of URLs that you can allow to set up a referrer:
>
> - A specific URL with an exact path: www.example.com/path
> - Any URL in a single subdomain, using a wildcard asterisk (*): sub.example.com/*
> - Any subdomain or path URLs in a single domain, using wildcard asterisks (*): *.example.com/*
> - A URL with a non-standard port: www.example.com:8000/*
>
> Note: query parameters and fragments are not currently supported; they will be ignored if you include them in an HTTP referrer.